# How to Use BOOL in IBACTION IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, boolean, ibaction

i need to connect an imap email server with below given -(BOOL) method

how can i call this method in IBACTION when connect button clicked?

```
- (BOOL) connectToHost: (NSString*) hostname
{
    socket_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_ < 0) {
        NSLog(@"socket");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(993);

    struct hostent* host = gethostbyname([hostname UTF8String]);
    unsigned int** ptr = (unsigned int **) host->h_addr_list;
    while (*ptr != NULL) {
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(*ptr);

        if (connect(socket_, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == 0) {
            break;
        }

        ptr++;
    }
    if (*ptr == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"connect");
    }

    return [[self readLine] isEqualToString: @"* OK"];
}
```

Comment: just make a typical on click method with IBACTION and then call connectToHost from within.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... call it from another method?

```
- (IBAction) connectButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [self connectToHost:@"Your host name goes here, variable _or_ constant! :D"];
}
```

Comment: You may want to do something if the `BOOL` evaluates to false, like display a `UIAlertView` informing the user that the connection failed.

Comment: **[self connectToHost:@"Your host name goes here, variable _or_ constant! :D"];** this take only one argument which is host name, i take hostname from textfield "imap.gmail.com" so my code is like **[self connectToHost:@"imap.gmail.com"]**
 when i put break points i see that it is terminated at above code 
**if (connect(socket_, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr)) == 0) {break;**
do you have any idea or suggestions to fix it?

Comment: @SpaceDust: No, and I suggest you create a new question for this, because it is a completely different question.